# How to filter python telnet print() output

Tags: python, telnetlib

I have a few projectors that i control with a python script using telnetlib, which works fine. I can also read the telnet output to get the current settings from them.

The issue i am having is that the telnet output gives me some unwanted characters and i would like to filter those out and show just the actual data.

```
#CURRENT SCRIPT
import time
import telnetlib
import os


port = 555
ipaddr = ('10.0.0.171',
          '10.0.0.172',
          '10.0.0.173',)
for ip in ipaddr:
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(ip, port,)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    tn.write(b"*gamma ?\r")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    tn.write(b"*power ?\r")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(tn.read_eager(), end = ' ')
    print("on " + ip)
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    tn.close
os.system("pause")
```

The output looks like this:

```
b'ack gamma = 3\r\nack power = 1\r\n' on 10.0.0.171
----------------------------------------------------
b'ack gamma = 3\r\nack power = 1\r\n' on 10.0.0.172
----------------------------------------------------
b'ack gamma = 3\r\nack power = 1\r\n' on 10.0.0.173
----------------------------------------------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

which basically returns the ACK command and the data with \r\n at the end

is it possible to filter those out and put a delimiter between?
something like:

```
| gamma = 3 | power = 1 | on 10.0.0.171
----------------------------------------------------
| gamma = 3 | power = 1 | on 10.0.0.172
----------------------------------------------------
| gamma = 3 | power = 1 | on 10.0.0.173
----------------------------------------------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Or if it is simpler to output these replies in a popup message box?
or highlight them  (different color)?

Working on Windows with Python 3.7.3

Any help would be much appreciated,  Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an instance of the bytes built-in type from the Telnet.read_eager() method and must decode it into a string using the [bytes.decode()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?bytes-and-bytearray-operations#bytes-and-bytearray-operations) method. Look at the following fragment.

```
ip = '10.1.1.30'
bs = b'ack gamma = 3\r\nack power = 1\r\n'
print(type(bs))
s = bs.decode()
print(type(s))
s = s.replace('\r\n', ' | ')
print('| '+ s + 'on ' + ip)
```

**Output:**

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'str'>
| ack gamma = 3 | ack power = 1 | on 10.1.1.30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode bytes to unicode string using `decode`:

```
In [1]: bs = b'hello world'

In [2]: bs
Out[2]: b'hello world'

In [3]: bs.decode('utf-8')
Out[3]: 'hello world'
```

And string can be encoded into bytes the same way using `encode`:

```
In [4]: s = '123456'

In [5]: s.encode()
Out[5]: b'123456'
```

Then along with regex to grab your desired information. For example:

```
import re
s = b'ack gamma = 3\r\nack power = 1\r\n on 10.0.0.171'.decode('utf-8')
ip_addr = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', s)[0] # 10.0.0.171
```